# How can I sum up values in a Razor MVC4 view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am coding the following into my Razor view:

```
        <ul class="message"
            data-elapsed="@Model.Events.Sum(event => event.Elapsed)"
            id="stats-list">
        @foreach (ViewEvent viewEvent in @Model.Events)
        {
            <li>@viewEvent.Description : @viewEvent.Elapsed ms</li>
        }
        <li class="close-bt"></li>
        </ul>
```

This gives me the following error:

```
<div class="block-content no-title no-padding">
Line 63:             <ul class="message"
Line 64:                 data-elapsed=@(Model.Events.Sum(event => event.Elapsed)) 
Line 65:                 id="stats-list">
Line 66:             @foreach (ViewEvent viewEvent in @Model.Events)
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected
```

When I comment out all of line 64 my code shows my view.

Is this not a correct way to get the sum?

Comment: You need "". Like this: data-elapsed="@Model.Events.Sum(event => event.Elapsed)"

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same error pointing to line 64

Comment: You definetely need those "". That was one problem. Another is that u duplicate the @ at line 66. It should be: @foreach (ViewEvent viewEvent in Model.Events){ /// code }
And by the way, that error is for bad razor code. The compiler doesn't know how to interpret your code. Your sum is ok.

Comment: I updated to show the full code.

Comment: Try to add data-elapsed = @{ // your code... }In Razor view if, for, foreach... needs Opening and closing curly braces @if{ ... }, @foreach{ ... }.

Comment: @Samantha you should use a viewmodel instead of doing sum in a view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the second @ from foreach. It should work:

```
<ul class="message"
            data-elapsed="@Model.Events.Sum(event => event.Elapsed)"
            id="stats-list">
        @foreach (ViewEvent viewEvent in Model.Events)
        {
            <li>@viewEvent.Description : @viewEvent.Elapsed ms</li>
        }
        <li class="close-bt"></li>
        </ul>
```